# Background-image resize using window-size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a project that requires a div a with background image to resize to the window height of the browser. That part works, but i am hung up on getting the background-size css class to change based on my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var mydivs = $("section#bottle,#bottle>div:nth-of-type(1)"), w = $(window);

  w.bind("load resize",function() {
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var windowWidth = 'auto';
        mydivs.css({width:w.width(),height:w.height()});
        mydivs.css({ backgroundSize : windowWidth + ' ' + windowHeight });

  });
```

})

Comment: Add 'px', for example mydivs.css({ backgroundSize : windowWidth + 'px ' + windowHeight + 'px' });
If that does not work, consider posting a JSFiddle so we can see it.

Comment: it's also `background-size`

Answer (score 2):

use css for this

> ```
>   <style> 
>
>
>       html { 
>           background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
>           -webkit-background-size: cover;
>           -moz-background-size: cover;
>           -o-background-size: cover;
>           background-size: cover;
>       }
>
>
> </style>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

could try just using css `background-size:cover` and or `background-size:100%`.

To handle the offsets / aspect ratio and various sizes, we can set the image larger ( to give it 'play' ) than we need and then set an over percentage eg .

`background-size:120%`

Comment: % background sizes also come in `background-size:100% auto`, `background-size:100% 100%`, `background-size:100% 120%` etc ..

Answer (score 0):

The key problem I have faced on this type of issue is css jquery as in the following example:

```
.css({backgroundSize: '400px 300px'});//won't work
.css(backgroundSize,'400px 300px');//works
```

So, first try changing

`mydivs.css({ backgroundSize : windowWidth + ' ' + windowHeight });`

with:

```
mydivs.css( backgroundSize , windowWidth + ' ' + windowHeight);
```

If it's not what you are having the problem then try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var mydivs = $("section#bottle,#bottle>div:nth-of-type(1)");

  w.bind("load resize",function() {
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var windowWidth = 'auto';
        mydivs.css({width:windowWidth + 'px',height:windowHeight + 'px'});
        mydivs.css({ backgroundSize : windowWidth + 'px' + ' ' + windowHeight + 'px' });

  });

})
```